# How to enable checking for arithmetic overflow globally in the ASP.NET 5 | MVC 6?

Tags: c#, error-handling, visual-studio-2015, settings, asp.net-core-mvc

There is a setting in the VS2013 MVC5 project:

[image]

It can be opened by

> Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced

But I can't find something like it in the VS2015 MVC6 project.

How to enable checking for arithmetic overflow globally now?

Answer (score 1):

In your `project.json` you can set [compiler options](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#user-content-compilation-options). It might be configurable from there. I currently am at my work pc (without asp.net 5), so I can't verify it. I would suggest you use Intellisense to see if it is available.

```
{
    "configurations": {
        "Debug": {
            "compilationOptions": {
                "define": ["DEBUG", "TRACE"]
            }
        },
        "Release": {
            "compilationOptions": {
                "define": ["RELEASE", "TRACE"],
                "optimize": true
            }
        }
    },
    "compilationOptions": {
        "define": ["SOMETHING"],
        "allowUnsafe": true,
        "warningsAsErrors" : true,
        "languageVersion": "experimental"
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE 1

It seems it is currently not supported in the compilations options. If you need this, I suggest you file a issue on github.

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime/Compilation/CompilerOptions.cs

---

### UPDATE 2

You might want to expand on [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1868).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunatly, IntellySence offer no suitable option. There are "allowUnsafe", "define", "delaySign", "emitEntryPoint", "keyFile", "languageVersion", "optimize", "useOssSigning", "warningAsErrors" only.

Comment: I might look into it more tonight when I am free, but if intellisense says no... all bets are off.